# Self assignment via send

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays `a` and `b`. I can rewrite `a = a + b` using `send` as

```
a = a.send(:+, b)
```

Is there a way to rewrite `a += b` using `send`, something like this?

```
a.send(:+=, b)
```

Comment: @sawa In my case the variable name (a) is bit lengthy So I wanted to reduce space, I use send to call :+, or :<< based on (b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with `+=` just like Sergio says, but you can do it with `concat`.

```
a.send(:concat, b)
```

Note that this is not exactly the same as doing `+=` because with `concat`, `a` will be referring to the same object as before whereas with `+=`, it will be a newly created object.

Comment: No Worries, Exactly What I wanted. Thanks. Awsome.

Answer (score 3):

`+` is an operator *and* a method. `+=` is just an operator, there's no corresponding method. it's a syntax shortcut for `a = a + b`. You can't use `:+=` with `send`.